# How to change the table my custom ContentProvider uses when querying?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

So I have My custom `ContentProvider`. Currently only the `onCreate()` method and the `query()` method do anything, so I will only show that.

---

```
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    openHelper = new SmartCalOpenHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return database.query("events_info", projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
}
```

---

Of course I have an inner class that sets up all the database info. The part I do not understand is how to change the table name, like `events_info` above dynamically depending on which class uses it. I currently have it calling that one table, but I need to be able to change it in order to reuse it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the `Uri` and extract whatever information you need to decide what kind of information the caller is asking for. See [the relevant documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContentURI) for further guidance.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you for the link. I will read it through. I didn't realize that is where I do it. Much appreciated

Comment: I am having a problem doing this. The documentation is very bad at explaining it. How do I correctly append my table with the URI to then Match it in content provider? I am using `Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, "events_info")` but it says the table does not exist. Am I doing it wrong?